# How to get the image bitmap of an ImageButton?

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have no problem doing:

```
currentImageButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

However, I have yet to be able to get the image bitmap back. I am trying to get the image bitmap BACK from the ImageButton and use it to set the background of my canvas.

```
currentImageButton.buildDrawingCache();
Drawable myDrawable = currentImageButton.getDrawable();
Bitmap anImage      = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

canvas.drawBitmap(getResizedBitmap(anImage, 1000, 1000));
```

None of this seems to work though. I've even tried using `myDrawable` to set change the background of my view, just incase it was something wrong with canvas but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you, please, confirm that the problem is in getting Bitmap, and not drawing it to canvas?

Comment: did you got the solution?

Answer (score -1):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageBitmapInstance.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
```